# thread affinity of UI controls in windows phone 7

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, uiview, windows-phone-7, thread-safety

How do I handle thread affinity issues in windows phone 7 when I'm building a multi-threaded application? A simple example is the user kicks of some long running process that is handled in another thread which updates a UI element when it's done. How do I get back to the main thread from the worker thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). (The same as in desktop Silverlight or WPF.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but can you please elaborate. How do I get a reference to the UI Dispatcher from the worker thread?

Comment: @davidk01: There's a `Dispatcher` property on even page/control. You'll need to fetch that property and make it available to whatever code is running your background task.